# Create a relation of more than three tables in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I have the following method that is causing me trouble as I try and create a relation of more than three tables in Yii:

```
public function relations()
{
     return array(
                 'info'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Software', 'ITEM_ID'),
                 'categories'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'ItemCategory',
                 'item_cat_relation(item_id, cat_id)',
                 'condition'=>'categories.cat_of_type=item_meta1.item_type_id'),
                 );
}
```

This code gives an error at `item_meta1.item_type_id`

Comment: Is item_meta1 the models base table? Or is it from one of the relations?

Comment: item_meta1 is model base table

Answer (score 0):

In general, Yii is not built to handle "three table relations". That being said, you *should* still be able to add a condition() to your relation query, I think the issue is just that you didn't JOIN the `item_meta1` table. You can do this two ways:

1) Add a JOIN clause to your relation:

```
return array(
  'categories'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'ItemCategory',
    'item_cat_relation(item_id, cat_id)',
    'join'=>'JOIN item_meta1 ON categories.cat_of_type=item_meta1.item_type_id'
  ),
);
```

1) Add a WITH clause to your relation (assuming you have a relation for the other table set up):

```
return array(
  'itemMeta'=>array(self::HAS_MANY, 'ItemMeta','item_type_id'), // I probably don't have this quite right, but you should get the idea
  'categories'=>array(self::MANY_MANY, 'ItemCategory',
    'item_cat_relation(item_id, cat_id)',
    'with'=>'itemMeta',
    'condition'=>'categories.cat_of_type=itemMeta.item_type_id')
  ),
);
```

I did not test any of that code even a little bit, but I have done similar things so it *should* work, in principle. :) Good luck!