# Changing the array that a HAS_MANY relation produces

Tags: php, yii

```
'driverNegotiation' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'DriverNegotiation', 'driver_id')
```

This produces an array of `negotiations` for my `Driver` object. The array is indexed from zero. Is there a way to *set the value used as an array key*, let's say `team_id` that can be found from `DriverNegotiation`?

Comment: Add [`'index' => 'team_id'`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHasManyRelation#index-detail) to the relation specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "set the value used as an array key". But if you mean get an array back from the driverNegotiation relation that is indexed by one of the `DriverNegotiation` tables values, rather than numerically then you can add the `index` parameter to the relation:

```
'driverNegotiation' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'DriverNegotiation', 'driver_id', 'index'=>'team_id')
```

Just be aware that wherever team_id clashes you will only get one result, it's almost equivalent to doing a group by.

**Update**
As per your comment about pulling down from a relation, it's not something I've ever done, but it might be doable. My guess would be, pull the relation down together using `'together'=>true` on the `with` and then specify an `index`:

```
'index'=>'`baseNegotiation`.`team_id`'
```

If that doesn't work I'm not sure where to go next and can't test at the minute, but I'd also try on the Yii Forums as the developers are excellent at responding over there.

Comment: That was what I meant, thanks! But now I have a another problem. In reality this team_id is located in base_negotiaton (sorry, I forgot that), which is related to DriverNegotiation `'baseNegotiation' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'BaseNegotiation', 'base_negotiation_id')`. Is there a way to use that as a key?

Comment: With your help and help from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702847/create-a-relation-of-more-than-three-tables-in-yii I got error: `Property "DriverNegotiation.baseNegotiation.team_id" is not defined.` So how I get rid of that DriverNegotiation from the beginning?

Comment: And now I realized that this whole problem could be solved with MANY_MANY relations... :)